# A triangle of numbers

Tags: code-golf, number

## Challenge

Make a triangle of numbers like below.

## How to?

Let say we get a numbers in the form of ab, for example `12`. We then create a triangle like below:
[image: Sorry for bad drawing!]

Sorry for my bad drawing!

First we have `12`, and we take sum of the two numbers `1` and `2`, which is `3`. In case the sum of two numbers are greater than 9, we just take the second number from the sum. For example if we have `49` then the sum will be `4+9=13`, we just take 3.

`12` is the number we input, which is line 1, `3` - its sum, is line 2. We now create line 3 by cross-adding. For example, Line 1 contain `12` is split to `1` and `2`, line 2 contain 3, so the line 3's first element will be the second element of line 1 plus line 2, and the second element of line 3 will be the first element of line 1 plus line 2. And remember, if the sum is greater than 9, just take the second number of the sum just like explained.

Now we come to line 4: the first element of line 4 now is calculated by line 2 plus the first element of line 3, and the third element of line 4 is line 2 plus the second element of line 3. The second element of line 3 - the middle, is the sum of all element in the previous line, which is line 3.

Now we come to line 5. Like line 4, the first and the last element of line 5 is calculated by the line 3's first element plus line 4 is first element and line 3's last element and line 4's last element. And the middle element of line 5, of course is the sum of all element in line 4. Now come to the second and the fourth element. You may notice that line 4 started to have the *middle element*, and the line 5's second element is just line 3's last element plus that middle element, and the line 5's fourth element is line 3's first element plus that middle element.

Line 6 is the same as line 5. And from now on, all the line just has 5 elements :)

## Rule

- The integer ab will be a positive integer and contain only two digits (from 10 -> 99)
  Program will let user input two line: the first line is the ab number, and the second line is the number of lines they want to output.
- The program will output the triangle as a bunch of numbers. See the example in the Output section below.
- The number of lines will always be greater than or equal to 5.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

## Output example

If we input:

```
12
6
```

It should print out:

```
12
3
54
897
33441
11528
```

Have fun and good luck!

### Note that I will select the winner after 4 more hour since the time edited.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861) This looks like a reasonably well-specified challenge, but for future reference, we strongly recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to the main site.

Comment: @pxeger Ok I will remember. But how long would it take (if the challenge meet every requirement) to go from sandbox to the main page? Thanks!

Comment: It's generally up to you how long you want to leave a challenge in the Sandbox, but the recommended time frame is a week, to properly allow people to give feedback and for you to address that

Comment: That would depend on the clarity and complexity of the challenge, how much it's seen and how much feedback it gets, etc. Feel free to ask in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) (our main chat room) for more feedback on your sandboxed challenge if your post isn't getting attention (since you have enough reputation to do so). Leaving it for at least a week is recommended to get enough attention and feedback.

Comment: I see that line 7 will have only five elements, if we call them `[a7, b7, c7, d7, e7]` then is `d7` the trailing digit of `c6 + a5` (rather than `c6 + b5`)? Also, I'd suggest avoiding the cumbersome IO (i.e. I would allow people to take two integers in \$[0..9]\$ and to output in any reasonable way, e.g. a list of lists of integers); challenges without such restrictions tend to be better received (unless the IO is a core part of the challenge, unlike here).

Comment: Could you provide some other test cases? I'd recommend to include at least one with more than 6 lines and clarify how the 7th line and next ones are generated (as already asked by Jonathan).

Comment: How to calculate the 7th line?

Comment: @tsh same as line 6. Line 7's first element is line 5's first element plus line 6's first element. Line 7's 5th element is line 5's 5th element plus line 6's 5th element. Line 7's middle element (3th) is the sum of all element in the line 6. Line 7's 2nd element is line 5's last element plus the middle element of line 6. And line 7's 4th element is line 5's first element plus line 6's middle element

Comment: @raspiduino calculate 6th relay on 5th and 4th. So I would suppose 7th line relay on 5th and 6th. But 4th only contains 3 numbers instead of 5 numbers as 5th line. So I don't know what is _same_ here mean.

Comment: @tsh you might want to see the edited comment

Comment: @raspiduino please add a test case with 7 or more lines, it's not obvious and everything should be in the main post

Comment: Ok, stupid of me at that time. This is somewhat similar to Pascal triangle, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 53 bytes

```
ÐˆO©D¸ˆ+Âˆ®+®3*ªÀ©ˆI4-F®н®ÅsD®Os®θ)¯¨θÂ‚€н0ª5∍+©ˆ}¯T%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWoAlf9vc2FiaWX//8OQy4ZPwqlEwrjLhivDgsuGwq4rwq4zKsKqw4DCqcuGSTQtRsKu0L3CrsOFc0TCrk9zwq7OuCnCr8KozrjDguKAmuKCrNC9MMKqNeKIjSvCqcuGfcKvVCX//1sxLCAyXQo5)

This uses lists of digits as I/O, [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##AWoAlf9vc2FiaWX//1PDkMuGT8KpRMK4y4Yrw4LLhsKuK8KuMyrCqsOAwqnLhkk0LUbCrtC9wq7DhXNEwq5Pc8Kuzrgpwq/CqM64w4LigJrigqzQvTDCqjXiiI0rwqnLhn3Cr1QlSsK7//8xMgo5) with the format in the challenge. The output is built row by row in the global array:

```python
Ð                    # push three copies of the input [w, a]
 ˆ                   # append one copy to the global array
  O©                 # take the sum s=w+a and store it in the register
    D¸               # duplicate s and wrap in a list
      ˆ              # append [s] to the global array
       +             # add s to each [w, a]
        Â            # duplicate and reverse the copy
         ˆ           # append [a+s, w+s] to the global array
          ®+         # add s to [w+s, a+s]
            ®3*      # push 3*s
               ª     # append: [w+2*s, a+2*s, 3*s]
                À    # rotate left
                 ©   # store in the register, from now the register always stores the last row
                  ˆ  # append [a+2*s, 3*s, w+2*s] to the global array

I4-                  # push second input - 4
   F              }  # iterate this many times
    ®н               # get the first value of the last row y   
      ®Ås            # middle value of last row
          ®O         # sum of last row
         D  s        # middle value again
             ®θ      # last value of last row
               )     # wrap all these numbers into a list      [y[0], y[m], sum(y), y[m], y[-1]]
    ¯¨θ              # push second-to-last row of global array (x)
       Â‚            # pair with its reverse                   [x, x[::-1]]
         €н          # push first element for each             [x[0], x[-1]]
           0ª        # append a 0                              [x[0], x[-1], 0]
             5∍      # extend to length 5                      [x[0], x[-1], 0, x[0], x[-1]]
               +     # add both lists element-wise             [y[0]+x[0], y[m]+x[-1], sum(y)+0, y[m]+x[0], y[-1]+x[-1]]
                ©ˆ   # save new row in register and add to global array

¯                    # push the global array
 T%                  # each number modulo 10
```

Comment: This is shorter, but I have selected OP's answer because they answer sooner than you and your answer is late. But thanks for the short answer!!!!

Comment: [Some minor alternatives for two parts of the code](https://tio.run/##Tc4hDsIwFIBh31O8zGBeyBjsBpxgFhBle2MNZU3WkgUHEwTDBbAgCCFTCAymQxPOsIuMocD@5vuV5lNBTVMV9fpQF9f3A1m18ewxQObaso3VGcEZKtJpx0CusjnEKgOTEPDQLLkEnuqcMgQt0pDAliA0cJkRj1YQCykpglyYBLRakElEOgOSmpwxe26DFkJmT69bC31p9vtw7cWvd3v8T7pb3bFpRj30sI8D9Ccf) (couldn't find anything shorter, though). Nice answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>195</s> <s>184</s> 181 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush)!

Based on OP's code

```python
def f(a,b):w=a//10;s=w+a;t=[[w,a],[s],[a+s,s+w],[2*s+a,s*3,2*s+w]];exec('*_,(x,*_,z),y=t;Y=y[len(y)//2];r,*t=t+[[x+y[0],z+Y,sum(y),x+Y,z+y[-1]]];print(*[x%10for x in r],sep="");'*b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYztCsIgGIVvRQYxP95wbr9KvJAhEq4cBeXGNNTd/LIf5/DwHDhric/FD8fxcDOasYWJXJOynItOBpWYlVFpncAa0KHGsgCBpUo9DcxCoAP8KRkjXXZ33NIb4Ay1dwJFRTmqot/O40I4743cgEYVmdaZFd0Z2NkI4fupM@SKe7VnYerbur18xFTnk@jmZUMZvTzaDAS3qqYhsqUTOWYsekAXcvwA)

Comment: This is short for python!

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 102 bytes

```
≔Ｉ⪪⮌Ｓ¹θ⊞υ⮌θ⊞υ⟦Σθ⟧≧⁺Σθθ⊞υθ≔⁺§υ¹θζ≔Ｅζ⁺ι§ζ⊕κη⊞υη≔ηζＦ⁻Ｎ⁴«≔⁺⊞ＯＥθ⁺κ§ηλΣζＥθ⁺κ§η⊕λζ⊞υζ≔Φη¬﹪λ²θ≔Φζ¬﹪λ²η»Ｅυ⭆ι﹪λχ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFNa4QwEIbP66/IcQIp1KX0sqelUPDgVtZj6cFqasLGqPlYiqW/3SZR0ZbuJSQz77zzTKZkhSrbQozjUWteS3gqtIG8E9zAmV6p0hQS2VmTG8VlDRgTFPujx4cos5qBJWgR9ngTfM1t4yJvLpQW3eR@5jUzkAmrCZrSv438febwIjiaRFb006fiICVoWCXOFgaCgpITtIhdKJGlog2VhlZwwdjzsk0btnqwyfGjVQhSLp1TmPZkm3eqwNU9YIy@ot2Wytu8dFQVplUBop8hLiuE8xWhrx9z8Jfbwi2tL8LzmLuFNzxmgmcujCNzZafWQNpWVrQgCNrjZSt/lMP/Sv8H31HmlmrCDK7NtGL/cL@56uN7j3QYx3gfPY53V/ED) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｉ⪪⮌Ｓ¹θ
```

Input the two digits, reverse them, split them, and cast to integer.

```
⊞υ⮌θ
```

Push the reverse of this (i.e. the original integers) to the list of results.

```
⊞υ⟦Σθ⟧
```

Push the sum as a list to the list of results, giving the second row.

```
≧⁺Σθθ
```

Add the two together, giving the third row. This is also the first row that takes part in diagonal calculations.

```
⊞υθ
```

Push this to the list of results.

```
≔⁺§υ¹θζ
```

Concatenate the second and third rows.

```
≔Ｅζ⁺ι§ζ⊕κη
```

Rotate the result and add it elementwise to produce the fourth row. This is also the second row that takes part in diagonal calculations.

```
⊞υη
```

Push this to the list of results.

```
≔ηζ
```

This is also the last result so far.

```
Ｆ⁻Ｎ⁴«
```

For the remaining rows...

```
≔⁺⊞ＯＥθ⁺κ§ηλΣζＥθ⁺κ§η⊕λζ
```

Calculate the diagonal sums before and after the sum of the previous row, thus producing the next row.

```
⊞υζ
```

Push this to the list of results.

```
≔Φη¬﹪λ²θ≔Φζ¬﹪λ²η
```

Shift all the rows back one, removing elements that do not participate in the diagonal sums.

```
»Ｅυ⭆ι﹪λχ
```

Output just the last digit of every element.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>517</s> <s>501</s> <s>410</s> 408 bytes

-32 bytes thanks to mypetlion

-3 bytes thanks to Dion

After fixing a bunch of bugs :), i come up with this:

```
a=int(input());b=int(input());t=[[a//10,a%10]];t.append([(t[0][0]+t[0][1])%10]);t.append([(t[0][1]+t[1][0])%10,(t[0][0]+t[1][0])%10]);t.append([(t[1][0]+t[2][0])%10,(t[2][0]+t[2][1])%10,(t[1][0]+t[2][1])%10])
for i in range(4,b):x=t[i-2];y=t[i-1];t.append([(x[0]+y[0])%10,(x[-1]+y[len(y)//2])%10,sum(y)%10,(x[0]+y[len(y)//2])%10,(x[-1]+y[-1])%10])
for i in range(b):
 for j in t[i]:print(end=str(j))
 print()
```

Input and output:

```
D:\Data\dev>python codegolf1.py
12
6
12
3
54
897
33441
11528
```

The first `12` and `6` is the input, all other number is output.

Comment: Change `t=[];t.append([a//10,a%10])` to `t=[[a//10,a%10]]` to save 11 bytes.

Comment: Change `for j in range(len(t[i])):print(t[i][j],end="")` to `for j in t[i]:print(j,end="")` to save 21 bytes.

Comment: Change `print(j,end="")` to `print(end=j)`

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: you can change your last 3 lines by : `for i in t:print(*i,sep="")` saving 33 bytes. You can also replace all the `t.append(element)` by `t+=[element]` saving another 20 bytes.

Comment: You can also change the definition of `t` by defining some variables: `A,a=map(int,input());b=int(input());c=(A+a)%10;d,e=(a+c)%10,(A+c)%10;t=[[A,a],[c],[d,e],[(c+d)%10,(d+e)%10,(c+e)%10]]` saves 78 bytes

Comment: You also can do all the modulo at the end, it won't affect the result so you can replace all the `(...)%10` by `...` and transform the last line by `for i in t[:b]:print(*[j%10for j in i],sep="")`. Note, I forgot to put the necessary `[:b]` to ensure the length of the output in my previous comment. Last thing, instead of doing `range(4,b):x=t[i-2];y=t[i-1];` you can do: `range(b):x=t[i+2];y=t[i+3];` It generates too much lines but who cares if it saves 2 bytes

Comment: here is a link with all the modifications : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5BCsIwELznFUUQEneltoKHSg59R8ghTaNGNIaaQvv6uhEVDzvMMLOzG@d0eYT9srRo5N1E7kNCH@KYuBCskyT5T1rZgmE9OmnAYguWJakUbWpUloaczKDHHhxacFqz02MofOFDMZhwdrwTzSST8lDr4/wme31MQDWT2mmYCXBS2yrTmwt8FmVZa3yOd6L4yfwZ3yzh/7Gkmk43ccjvb9R1Xe2ydc2WpzYX5WollqWq2eEF "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: you can define `N=len(y)//2` to avoid having it twice [Updated link with all modifications](https://tio.run/##TY5NasMwEIX3OoUxFKTMlNgOZGGjhS/gCwgtZFlJFBpFuArYp3dGoTRZzOM9vvmLa7rcw2HbejTyZiL3IaEP8ZG4EGyUFPl/tLIHwyZ00oDFHixLUima1KgsFZHsYMIJHFpwWrPTfS584UMxm3B2fBTtIpPy0OhufZmD7gb54wJfxX7fdAlo5aIqDSsJLuq7znbQ@Pu4UQ/@seHNSD8PJdWOuo1zfn2nrl91ldE1I09bXJRlKbatbtjxCQ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: or better `Y=y[len(y)//2]` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7NisIwEL7nKYqwkOzMolXwUMmhj1GGOaRpdCMaQ43QPH03kWXZw3x8P/MXc/p@hMO69mj03UTpQ0If4itJpcSoi5R/0uoejJjQaQMWe7AiaaIyyUi2VEkqgwkncGjBMYvzY25840Mzm3BxclTdohN52PMpv8mBT4POdHNBZrXdFj9B2brQjiEXwIW@WoYBn6976cB3MPy6ueL/K4m6kbs4178/6frR7mp0rZFnfLqoNxu1ru1eHH8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 54 bytes

```
.ị+U,$€Ḣ$}Ṛṭ@FṖS;`ʋ
“½“¿“€“ç!‘Dṫ-ç@/ṭƊ⁸¡EÐḟUṚ;@Ʋ€ḋ%⁵ḣ⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/v4e5u7VAdlUdNax7uWKRS@3DnrIc71zq4Pdw5Ldg64VQ316OGOYf2goj9QAKoCkgeXq74qGGGy8Odq3UPL3fQB6o/1vWoccehha6HJzzcMT8UaIa1w7FNYCO7VR81bn24YzFQ/v///2b/DXWMAA)

A set of links taking the left argument as the number of rows and the right as the initial integers. Returns a list of lists of integers.

If the IO is inflexible, [here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/v4e5u7VAdlUdNax7uWKRS@3DnrIc71zq4Pdw5Ldg64VQ316OGOYf2goj9QAKoCkgeXq74qGGGy8Odq3UPL3fQB6o/1vWoceehha6HJzzcMT8UaIa1w7FNYCO7XapVHzVufbhjceT///8Njf6bAQA) is a solution for 56 bytes that takes the arguments in the opposite order, the starting point as a single integer and prints the number triangle to STDOUT.

### Explanation

#### Helper link

Take the previous line on the left and the last but one on the right and generate the next line

```
.ị                  | Last and first items in the most recent line
  +     $}          | Add to the following applied to the last but one line:
   U,$€             | - Pair a reversed version of each list member to itself
       Ḣ            | - And then just take the first of these
          Ṛ         | Reverse order
           ṭ@     ʋ | Tag on the following (effectively applied to the previous line)
             F      | - Flatten
              Ṗ     | - Remove last
               S    | - Sum
                ;`  | - Concatenate to itself
```

#### Main link

```
“½“¿“€“ç!‘                          | [[10],[11],[12],[23,33]]
          D                         | Convert to decimal digits [[[1,0]],[[1,1]],[[1,2]],[[2,3],[3,3]]]
                 Ɗ⁸¡                | Repeat the following the number of times indicated by the original left argument
           ṫ-                       | - Take the last two list members
             ç@/                    | - Call the helper link using the last line as the left argument and the penultimate one as the right
                ṭ                   | - Tag the new line onto the end of the list
                           Ʋ€       | For each line:
                    EÐḟ             | - Filter out items where both members of the list are equal
                       U            | - Reverse each list member
                        Ṛ           | - Reverse order of list members
                         ;@         | - Concatenate to existing list
                             ḋ      | Dot product with starting integers
                              %⁵    | Mod 10
                                ḣ⁸  | Take the number of lines indicated by the original left argument
```

Comment: Wow, super tiny!

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 226 bytes

```javascript
R=readline
v=R()
h=(n,k=--n<4?n:5,g=(i,j,s=`1
12
233
35845
51508`.split`
`[i])=>s?s[j]*v[0]+v*s[(i<3?i:4)-j]:j-2?g(i-2,j%3*4)+g(i-1,j&4|j%2*2):(v- -v[0])*'093859835433'[i%12])=>k--?h(n,k)+g(n-1,k)%10:n?h(n)+`
`:v
print(h(R()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY/NaoQwGEX3eYpu7CQxKfkFJ0zqO8xWBKUj4xenqRgJFPru1izvhcM9N4x5TF8brDtPKzym7fsnLtPvcdz9No2PF8QJZX/HBM0eR7Z4zuPNtNFZ9vQYWGDJDxJJhZTWSNvGWGSlFc3wkdYX7AMaOuiJ/0xt6kJPcyf6OtPUYbjpFpwhPPQucNU@MXDFQqWpIXUJkoV38xcqRRVxOPM3XmBCL@KqG3tttDVaXzqopCoDC@ftXBQLHU96IZUULpaS1KeHy2jdIO54xucfQo6jWIt/)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>203</s>  198 bytes

Expects `(N)(n)`, where `N` is the initial number as a string and `n` is the number of lines.

```javascript
N=>n=>(s=7,g=k=>k<n?`${F=n=>n>k-2?k-n:F(++n)+F(++n),A=[d=s+F(1),b=F``,c=s+F(2),s+=a,a=F(-1)],[41,1,14,134][k]||10324}
`.replace(/./g,n=>(A[n]*N[0]+A["24031"[n]]*N)%10)+g(k+1,a+=k>3?b+c+d:b):'')(a=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7NSsQwFEb3PkZRJndy20naiFC8Kd10OS8QAk1/pmhKOkzEjeOz16h8i8M5q@/dfbo43t6uH3nYpnm/0H4mHUizSC@4kCftX0PTP351lGrQPi8bn4e6Y5wH4P/AlsxEMZkEHKjrexz/tASMnBw66lguwaJREtMUykpZ4@39LkVVqu@HvrjN19WNMzsVpwV/H7Qm2OPZCMtbk5VKVDJLJSV4kgL4wjyX6Dh5XTUDH/lUD1AfDsAcCdjHLcRtnYt1W9iFZbLMgMlngP0H)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>295</s> <s>292</s> <s>289</s> <s>281</s> 272 bytes

```python
a,b=map(int,input())
e=[[a,b],[a+b],[b+a+b,a+a+b],[3*b+a+a,3*a+3*b,3*a+b+b]]
for i in range(3,int(input())-1):f=e[i];e.append([e[i-1][0]+f[0],e[i][len(e[i])//2]+e[i-1][-1],sum(f),f[len(f)//2]+e[i-1][0],e[i-1][-1]+f[-1]])
for i in e:
 for j in i:print(j%10,end="")
 print()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7LDoMgELzzFcSkCchaX0kPNn4J4YAptJiKxOqhX28XtWl6YHaHmZ1MeM@P0dfrqqFrBx2Y8zM4H5aZcU5MKyUKCqQWETuBE7TYWZ1GrqFOtcB9mx0qithxoo46Tyft74bVmDizb2pW8sa2Rjp1NWcdgvE3JpFmpZKFEhYBoiqfxrO48DyvlDgc@OC1DMxysJvD/sn77WHELETFf31MQ2gkfSSuCVMs1p/KArBFmySc0P2Pr2tZkcsH)

-11 bytes thanks to @raspiduino

-9 bytes thanks to @MarcMush

Comment: You can change line 6 in your code to `for j in i:print(end=str(j)[-1])` to save 2 bytes!

Comment: In `e.append([e[i-1][0]+e[i][0],e[i][len(e[i])//2]+e[i-1][-1],sum(e[i]),e[i][len(e[i])//2]+e[i-1][0],e[i-1][-1]+e[i][-1]])` you call e[i] multiple times so you should define e[i] as something and call it. That will save lots of bytes!

Comment: you can use `a,b=map(int,input())` as suggested by @Jakque in @raspiduino's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229365/98541)

Comment: @MarcMush dammit. Knew there was a way to do that input efficiently

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>162</s> <s>159</s> <s>153</s> <s>148</s></sup> 144 bytes

-6 bytes from [ovs's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229374/98541)

```
!x=x.%10
~L=L[end]
(a,b)$n=.![(a,b);c=a+b;((b,a).+c,(b,c,a).+2c)>n]
(l,L)>n=n<3?l:[l;(L,(l[1]+L[1],(N=L[end÷2+1])+~l,sum(L),N+l[1],~l+~L))>n-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBCsIwFATQfU/RQoUf8i2mLkRr6gVCLxCySFMXlW8QSqGC5FoewIPFWDfDW8zMbabRHmIsFrlUG7HLgpJKX/1gMrDYs9LLqtArGyct7xuAHi2ruMMEt7J2rPVpQKgSpD/vL3TS1IBCIC0MVykQuv/z511zYRgPhNN8B8Ww478WBuJBsfSwFSaCwJqVx/zV5sM4Pcg@4xc)

takes the initial number as 2 numbers and output is a list of tuples

[+10 bytes with stricter I/O](https://tio.run/##JcxBCoMwFEXRuatQsPBDfsXYQWlt7AaCGwgZJNqBkqYFESyUbMsFuLA0bSePM3jccbaDPoaQLXx8DA6WYsdKknjBhby5XiUmd7zIpJSam21lJRql6o5ramoAg5oUtMOI7seqI41TCVgUEdxdDld7lrYGgWAlU1TEQWj/9W2tKFOEeovTfAdBsKXfF3pLvSCxsGcqsCo/pe8m7YfpafUrfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 205 bytes

```hs
l=last
x%y|m<-y!!div(length y)2=x:y%[x!!0+y!!0,l x+m,sum y,x!!0+m,l x+l y]
a#b|s<-a+b=[a,b]:[s]:[s+b,a+s]%[3*s-a,3*s,3*s-b]
main=do[a,b]<-getLine;n<-readLn;mapM(putStrLn.map(l.show))$take n$read[a]#read[b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpLCoMwGIT3niJSBW0SaS10UfUGdtVlyOIPBhWTtJjYGvDuVl18M8yjAztIpdZVVQqsC@bYL7qkPgyb/psoaVrXIZ/m1fzwMZvD8IK37UIUmrEmdtLIk6PVR6WQ5wGcxGJLClhUDIjgD2Z3sCCALY/Z7WwpkE13qOCBht5Uzfs4l7SVru6NLExJRwlNbQoNn2fymdzLjbXJtpSozHbvX5pGDgaJTLQfGfDT4YKv6zUP7n8)